# laravel livewire intervention images

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

I am trying to use Intervention image with Livewire to reduce the sizes and I am not succeeding. They can guide me or tell me if Livewire may not allow it.

I am trying to pass this methodology:

```
foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {
             $imgUrl = $pathGaleria->store('imagenesPropiedades');

             $img = imgPropiedades::create([
               'url' => $imgUrl,
               'property_id' => $this->propiedadId
             ]);
```

to this other way:

```
foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {
            $imgUrl = $pathGaleria->store('imagenesPropiedades');
            Image::make($pathGaleria)->resize(1200, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })
            ->save($imgUrl);
            $img = imgPropiedades::create([
                'url' => $imgUrl,
                'property_id' => $this->propiedadId
            ]);

        }
```

but the page remains blank. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this today, may  work for you

https://gist.github.com/daugaard47/659984245d31b895d00ee5dcbdee44ec

+

$images = Collection::wrap($request->file('file'));

```
    $images->each(function ($image) use ($id) {
        $basename = Str::random();
        $original = $basename . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $thumbnail = $basename . '_thumb.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        ImageManager::make($image)
            ->fit(250, 250)
            ->save(public_path('/images/' . $thumbnail));

        $image->move(public_path('/images/'), $original);

        Model::create([
          
        ]);
    });
```